# Excel Nested IF statement with various text conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am creating IF statements in Excel to budget according to the discipline of engineers. I want:

```
IF(H5="CIVIL") then print for me value (I5*5000)
IF(H5="ARCHITECT") then print for me value (I5*3000)
IF(H5="ELECTRIC") then print for me value (I5*3000)
IF(H5="MECHANIC") then print for me value (I5*2000)
```

I am using a nested IF statement:

```
 =IF(H5="CIVIL",I5,I5*5000,IF(H5="ARCHITECT",I5,I5*3000,IF(H5="ELECTRIC",I5,I5*3000,IF(H5="MECHANIC",I5,I5*2000))))
```

but I see the message "You've entered too many arguments for this function".

How can I use the formula without any problem?

Comment: Try this
=IF(H5="CIVIL",I5*33000,IF(H5="ARCHITECT",I5*16000,IF(H5="ELECTRIC",I5*12000,IF(H5="MECHANIC",I5*10000))))

Comment: In previous time i used that way but not work my function is correct. when i use only CIVIL,ARCHITECT,ELECTRIC AND MECHANIC it is work but when i use two statement not work

Comment: The logic for nested IFs remains the same in any language you use
IF( condition1, value1, IF( condition2, value2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(H5="CIVIL",5000,IF(OR(H5="ARCHITECT",H5="ELECTRIC"),3000,2000))*I5
```

Comment: don't show me the error message but when i use CIVIL or ARCHITECT or ELECTRIC text every time multiple I5 Cell by 2000 and not multiple by 5000 for civil and 3000 for architect

Comment: "double inverted commas"

Answer (score 1):

There will be more professions with more values, so a "single formula" approach is second best. You should use a table with profession and value, and use VLOOKUP, then you can change values and add professions as you like without updating spaghetti formula code ... e.g.

```
       A        B
1    Civil    5000
2    Arch     3000
3    Elec     3000
4    Mech     2000
```

Specifying a profession in `H5`, you would use the following formula in `I5`:

```
=VLOOKUP(H5,A1:B4,2,FALSE)
```

Looking at your edit ... one more reason NOT to hide the unit cost in a formula, because in 2016 the rates might be different --> use a table!

Comment: please help me i don't understand your explain

Comment: well ... I just abbreviated ARCHITECT by Arch ... use whatever ... and of course, if you have to multiply the rate found by VLOOKUP based on a profession in `H5` with hours specified in -say- `I5`, you'd say `=I5*VLOOKUP(H5, ... )` ... the message here really is to use a table **once** to specify the rates in **one** place, and then retrieve the values of that table using VLOOKUP rather than hardcoding important values into formulae.

Comment: @pnuts re delimiters ... my bad !! I was able to mentally "translate" the first as I was typing, for the others my (Austrian) autopilot apparently took over ... corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open your formula in a text editor and check it. I use line breaks to separate arguments. If you don't comment like I did you can even reimplement the now formatted formula. Saved me a lot of times.
Also, I've found your formula's hiatus:

```
=IF(
H5="CIVIL",   'test
I5,           'If True
I5*5000,      'If False
IF(           'WAT
H5="ARCHITECT",
I5,I5*3000,IF(H5="ELECTRIC",I5,I5*3000,IF(H5="MECHANIC",I5,I5*2000))))
```